# Empty array instead of scraped data in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I'm learning Pools and just want to scrape Craiglist and to have an array of titles. I have written the program that generally works (did various tests) but in the end results in printing empty array.

Here is my code:

```
from multiprocessing.spawn import freeze_support
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

scraped_data = []

def generate_urls():
    urls = []
    start = 0
    while start < 3000:
        url=f"https://newyork.craigslist.org/d/jobs/search/jjj?lang=en&cc=gb?s={start}"
        urls.append(url)
        start += 120
    return urls

def scrape_page_titles(url):
    global scraped_data
    r = requests.get(url)
    html_doc = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    titles = soup.find_all("a", class_="result-title")
    scraped_data.extend([title.text for title in titles])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    urls = generate_urls()
    p = Pool(3)
    p.map(scrape_page_titles, urls)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
    toc = time.perf_counter()

    result_time = toc - tic

    print(f"Parsing executed in {result_time:0.4f} seconds")
    print(scraped_data)
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Where `scraped_data` is defined?

Comment: it's at the top in global scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `scraped_data` as global variable in multi-processing context. In fact you have 4 instances of `scraped_data`. One for the main process and 3 others for your 3 processes, variables are not shared between process. Your parallel function have to return data to the main process:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import bs4
import requests
import time
import itertools

def generate_urls():
    ...  # nothing change here

def scrape_page_titles(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    html_doc = r.text

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    titles = soup.find_all("a", class_="result-title")
    return [title.text for title in titles]  # <- return collected data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    urls = generate_urls()
    with mp.Pool(3) as pool:  # <- use context manager, more readable
        data = pool.map(scrape_page_titles, urls)  # <- collect data
    scraped_data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))  # <- and merge ones
    toc = time.perf_counter()

    result_time = toc - tic

    print(f"Parsing executed in {result_time:0.4f} seconds")
    print(scraped_data)
```